# Accessing Nested Object in JSON array data

Tags: swift, codable

I have JSON data which has JSON objects in the array. I need to bind those properties to the buttons, so when a button is clicked, an `Int` value is given to it.

JSON data:

```json
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "string",
  "age": 0,
  "gender": "string",
  "dateofBirth": "string",
  "mobileNumber": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "address": "string",
  "countryId": 0,
  "stateId": 0,
  "districtId": 0,
  "constituencyId": 0,
  "activityLevels": [
    {
      "voterJanasenaActivity_Id": 0,
      "janasenaActivity_Id": 0
    }
  ],
  "awareOfJanasenaPrinciples": true,
  "awareWhcichPrinciples": [
    {
      "voterJanasenaPrinciple_Id": 0,
      "janasenaPrinciple_Id": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to bind `janasenaPrinciple_Id` and `janasenaActivity_Id` to buttons, so when they are clicked, an `Int` value is assigned to it.

```swift
class NewVoterModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var aadharNumber: String = ""
    @Published var address: String = ""
    @Published var id: Int = 999
    @Published var mobileNumber: String = ""
    @Published var gender: String = ""
    @Published var name: String = ""
    @Published var dateofBirth = Date()
    @Published var countryId: Int = 1
    @Published var stateId: States? = nil
    @Published var districtId: Districts? = nil
    @Published var constituencyId: Constituency? = nil
    @Published var email: String = ""
    @Published var activityLevels: [activityLevel] = []
    @Published var awareWhcichPrinciples: [awareWhcichPrinciples] = []
    
    
    init() {}
}

struct activityLevel: Codable{
    var voterJanasenaActivity_Id: Int = 0
    var janasenaActivity_Id: Int
}
struct awareWhcichPrinciples: Codable{
    var voterJanasenaPrinciple_Id: Int = 0
    var janasenaActivity_Id: Int
}
```

POST API call:

```swift
class NewVoterViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    
    //****--POST API CALL--****//
    func makePostAPI(id: Int, name: String, address: String, aadharNumber: String, email: String, dateofBirth: String, mobileNumber: String, stateId: Int, districtId: Int, constituencyId: Int, countryId: Int = 1, gender: String, awareOfJanasenaPrinciples: Bool, voterJanasenaPrinciple_Id: Int, voterJanasenaActivity_Id: Int ) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://janasenanriconnectwebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Voter/CreateVoter") else {
            return
        }
        
        print("Making api call..")
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let body: [String: AnyHashable] = [
              "name": name,
              "gender": gender,
              "dateofBirth": dateofBirth,
              "mobileNumber": mobileNumber,
              "aadharNumber": aadharNumber,
              "email": email,
              "address": address,
              "countryId": countryId,
              "stateId": stateId,
              "districtId": districtId,
              "constituencyId": constituencyId,
              "awareOfJanasenaPrinciples": awareOfJanasenaPrinciples,
              "voterJanasenaPrinciple_Id": voterJanasenaPrinciple_Id,
              "voterJanasenaActivity_Id": voterJanasenaActivity_Id,
              

        ]
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: .fragmentsAllowed)
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil  else {
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(NewVoter.self, from: data)
                print("SUCCESS: \(response)")
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Here is the SwiftUI View I want to implement those properties:

```swift
struct SampleView: View {
    
    @StateObject var VM2 = NewVoterModel()
    @StateObject var VM = NewVoterViewModel()
    
    @EnvironmentObject var VM1: PersonInfoViewModel
    
    @State private var stateChecked: Bool = false
    @State private var districtChecked: Bool = false
    @State private var constituencyChecked: Bool = false
    
    @State private var principle1: Bool = false
    @State private var principle2: Bool = false
    @State private var principle3: Bool = false
    @State private var principle4: Bool = false
    @State private var principle5: Bool = false
    @State private var principle6: Bool = false
    @State private var principle7: Bool = false
    
    @Binding var stateId: States?
    @Binding var districtId: Districts?
    @Binding var constituencyId: Constituency?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Form{
                Section{
                    Text("Have you taken part in any party activities?")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    HStack{
                        Toggle("", isOn: $stateChecked)
                            .labelsHidden()
                            .toggleStyle(.checklist)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                stateChecked.toggle()
                                districtChecked = false
                                constituencyChecked = false
                                VM2.voterJanasenaActivity_Id = 1
                            }
                        Text("State Level")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    HStack{
                        Toggle("", isOn: $districtChecked)
                            .labelsHidden()
                            .toggleStyle(.checklist)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                districtChecked.toggle()
                                stateChecked = false
                                constituencyChecked = false
                                VM2.voterJanasenaActivity_Id = 2
                            }
                        Text("District Level")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    HStack{
                        Toggle("", isOn: $constituencyChecked)
                            .labelsHidden()
                            .toggleStyle(.checklist)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                constituencyChecked.toggle()
                                districtChecked = false
                                stateChecked = false
                                VM2.voterJanasenaActivity_Id = 3
                            }
                        Text("Constituency Level")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                Section{
                    Text("Which 2 principles do you like in it?")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    HStack{
                        Toggle("", isOn: $principle1)
                            .labelsHidden()
                            .toggleStyle(.checklist)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                VM2.voterJanasenaPrinciple_Id = 1
                            }
                        Text("Caste mindedness.")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    HStack{
                        Toggle("", isOn: $principle2)
                            .labelsHidden()
                            .toggleStyle(.checklist)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                VM2.voterJanasenaPrinciple_Id = 2
                            }
                        Text("Religion-free politics.")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    HStack{
                        Toggle("", isOn: $principle3)
                            .labelsHidden()
                            .toggleStyle(.checklist)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                VM2.voterJanasenaPrinciple_Id = 3
                            }
                        Text("Culture that respects languages.")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    HStack{
                        Toggle("", isOn: $principle4)
                            .labelsHidden()
                            .toggleStyle(.checklist)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                VM2.voterJanasenaPrinciple_Id = 4
                            }
                        Text("A society that preserves cultures.")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    HStack{
                        Toggle("", isOn: $principle5)
                            .labelsHidden()
                            .toggleStyle(.checklist)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                VM2.voterJanasenaPrinciple_Id = 5
                            }
                        Text("A nationalism that does not ignore regionlism.")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    HStack{
                        Toggle("", isOn: $principle6)
                            .labelsHidden()
                            .toggleStyle(.checklist)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                VM2.voterJanasenaPrinciple_Id = 6
                            }
                        Text("Environmentally friendly development.")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    HStack{
                        Toggle("", isOn: $principle7)
                            .labelsHidden()
                            .toggleStyle(.checklist)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                VM2.voterJanasenaPrinciple_Id = 7
                            }
                        Text("Uncompromising fight against corruption.")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                Section{
                    Button {
                        print("Clicked")
                        
                        VM.makePostAPI(id: VM1.id, name: VM1.name, address: VM1.address, aadharNumber: VM1.aadharNumber, email: VM1.email, dateofBirth: VM1.birthdayString, mobileNumber: VM1.mobileNumber, stateId: stateId?.id ?? 0, districtId: districtId?.id ?? 0, constituencyId: constituencyId?.id ?? 0, gender: VM1.gender, awareOfJanasenaPrinciples: VM2.awareOfJanasenaPrinciples, voterJanasenaPrinciple_Id: VM2.voterJanasenaPrinciple_Id, voterJanasenaActivity_Id: VM2.voterJanasenaActivity_Id)
                    } label: {
                        Text("Submit")
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CheckboxViewModel: ToggleStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        Button {
            configuration.isOn.toggle()
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: configuration.isOn ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
                .symbolVariant(configuration.isOn ? .fill : .none)
        }
        .tint(configuration.isOn ? .red : .black)
    }
}

extension ToggleStyle where Self == CheckboxViewModel{
    static var checklist: CheckboxViewModel { .init() }
}
```

How can I connect nested entities to `SampleView`, so when I toggle the buttons it gives `Int` values to the `janasenaPrinciple_Id` and `janasenaActivity_Id`. I'm able to access rest of the entities in the json body, except those two.

The result I'm getting when I looked into the GET response body:

```json
{
    "id": 282,
    "name": "Harry Potter",
    "age": null,
    "gender": "male",
    "dateofBirth": "30/09/1994",
    "mobileNumber": "545235235",
    "aadharNumber": "213123123",
    "email": "naqdcscaavw@koo.com",
    "countryId": 1,
    "stateId": 1,
    "districtId": 1,
    "constituencyId": 6,
    "activityLevels": null,
    "awareOfJanasenaPrinciples": null,
    "awareWhcichPrinciples": null
}
```

That is all the code I have used in my project which is related to those entities. Can you please tell what else I'm missing here.  Most of Stackoverflow questions are related to GET API, but I need those to make POST API call.

Comment: If you can get null back for some json keys then you need to make the corresponding property optional. The properties you are asking about are inside arrays but in your view code you don’t seem to be working with arrays so it’s hard to understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your own custom JSON decoding logic

```
class Object: ObservableObject, Decodable {
    @Published var name: String
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { 
        case name
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Question, 1. Do I have to do for the Nested objects as well? Since the entities `janasenaPrinciple_Id` and `janasenaActivity_Id` are in the Nested object. 2. Can you confirm if my HTTP request for POST API is good or not? Since the response body is showing `Null` value instead of `Int` values.  @Javon718

Comment: Why is a custom decoding logic needed?

Comment: I have noticed that if my object has @Published in it xcode no longer automatically synthesized the init.

Comment: There is no reason to have `NewVoterModel` Decodable, the OP is JSON decoding `NewVoter.self` not `NewVoterModel`.

Comment: I updated it. The title doesn't matter. What I'm saying to him is you need to make it decodable.

Comment: @Jevon718 I think you misunderstood the previous comment by sumida, it looks like it’s not the observable object that is used for decoding by OP but some other type that isn’t included in the question.